# Virtual key to character conversion depending on the locale

Tags: c++, winapi

I can't translate a character according to the set keyboard layout.Tried several variants, but it doesn't work.

I enter the Russian character "Л" and the output is getting the English character "K". There is no translation. The input should be "Л" and the output should be "Л".

First version:

```cpp
std::wstring StandardKeyToStringW(DWORD VKey)
{
    static WCHAR name[32] = { 0 };
    static BYTE kbState[256] = { 0 };
    DWORD idThread;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), &idThread);
    long code = MapVirtualKeyExW(VKey, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC, GetKeyboardLayout(idThread)) << 16;
    GetKeyboardState(kbState);
    ToUnicode(VKey, code, kbState, name, 32, 0);
    return name;
}
```

Second version:

```cpp
std::wstring StandardKeyToStringW(DWORD VKey)
{
    static WCHAR name[32] = { 0 };
    DWORD idThread;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), &idThread);
    long code = MapVirtualKeyExW(VKey, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC, GetKeyboardLayout(idThread)) << 16;
    GetKeyNameTextW(code, name, 32);
    return name;
}
```

Comment: What are the inputs and outputs? What should they be?  What locale? How do you know it's wrong? (It might be the right codes but you're printing them out wrong somewhere else, I dunno.) You probably should include headers, although apparently Windows.h gets them all.

Comment: I enter the Russian character "Л" and the output is the English character "K". The translation does not happen. It should be "Л" on the input and "Л" on the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual key to character conversion depending on the locale:

```cpp
std::wstring StandardKeyToStringW(DWORD VKey)
{
    static WCHAR name[32] = L"";
    static BYTE kbState[256] = { 0 };
    DWORD idThread;
    idThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), nullptr);
    long code = MapVirtualKeyExW(VKey, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC, 
                                 GetKeyboardLayout(idThread)) << 16;
    ToUnicodeEx(VKey, MapVirtualKey(VKey, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC), kbState, name, 
                                    32, 0, GetKeyboardLayout(idThread));
    return name;
}
```